# Make two SharedPreferences

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I using shared preferences in my xamarin Android project.

I want to know can I use two Shared Prefences in two different activities

Like this in first activity

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();

            editor.PutString ("title", (string)(firstitem ["post_title"]));
            editor.PutString ("price", (string)(firstitem ["price"] + " грн"));
            editor.PutString ("weight", (string)(firstitem ["weight"] + "г"));

            editor.Apply ();
```

And this and second activity:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs2 = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor2 = prefs2.Edit ();

            editor2.PutString ("title", (string)(firstitem ["post_title"]));
            editor2.PutString ("price", (string)(firstitem ["price"] + " грн"));
            editor2.PutString ("weight", (string)(firstitem ["weight"] + "г"));

            editor2.Apply ();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the data in separate places you can use a different `SharedPreferences` file. For example in the first activity,

```
var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("first_activity", FileCreationMode.Private);
var editor = prefs.Edit();
editor.PutString("key", "value1");
editor.Commit();
```

Then in the second do this,

```
var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("second_activity", FileCreationMode.Private);
var editor = prefs.Edit();
editor.PutString("key", "value2");
editor.Commit();
```

Notice the first parameter in `GetSharedPreferences()` which takes a filename.

Comment: How I can show what in preferences in another activity?